# Synchronize work between CPU and GPU within single command buffer using MTLSharedEvent

Tags: swift, macos, metal

I am trying to use `MTLSharedEvent` along with `MTLSharedEventListener` to synchronize computation between GPU and CPU, as in example provided by Apple (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronization/synchronizing_events_between_a_gpu_and_the_cpu). Basically what I want to achieve is have work split into 3 parts executed in order, like so:

1. GPU computation part 1
2. CPU computation based on results from GPU computation part 1
3. GPU computation part 2 after CPU computation

My problem is that `eventListener` block is always called before command buffer is being scheduled for execution, which make my CPU task execute first in order.

To simplify the case, let’s use simple commands that fill `MTLBuffer` with certain values (my original use case is more complicated, as using compute encoders with custom shaders, but behaves the same):

```swift
let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let queue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
let event = device.makeSharedEvent()!
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myqueue")
let eventListener = MTLSharedEventListener(dispatchQueue: dispatchQueue)

let metalBuffer = device.makeBuffer(length: 2048, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared)!

let buffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer()!

NSLog("Start - signaled value: \(event.signaledValue)")

event.notify(eventListener, atValue: 1) { event, value in
    // CPU work 
    let pointer = metalBuffer.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    for i in 0..<512 {
        (pointer + i).pointee = (pointer + i).pointee  + 1;
    }

    NSLog("Event notification - signaled value: \(value), buffer status: \(buffer.status.rawValue)")
    event.signaledValue = 2
}

// GPU work part 1
let encoder1 = buffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()!
encoder1.fill(buffer: metalBuffer, range: .init(0...127), value: 22)
encoder1.endEncoding()

// signal with 1 to start CPU task 
buffer.encodeSignalEvent(event, value: 1)
// wait for value >= 2 to proceed
buffer.encodeWaitForEvent(event, value: 2)

// GPU work part 2
let encoder2 = buffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()!
encoder2.fill(buffer: metalBuffer, range: .init(128...511), value: 255)
encoder2.endEncoding()

buffer.addScheduledHandler { buffer in
    NSLog("Buffer scheduled - signaled value: \(event.signaledValue)")
}
buffer.addCompletedHandler { buffer in
    NSLog("Buffer completed - signaled value: \(event.signaledValue)")
}

buffer.commit()
buffer.waitUntilCompleted()
```

Output:

```
2022-01-09 23:46:08.774 Sync[76882:3531755] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2022-01-09 23:46:08.805 Sync[76882:3531755] Start - signaled value: 0
2022-01-09 23:46:08.808 Sync[76882:3531764] Event notification - signaled value: 1, buffer status: 2 (Commited)
2022-01-09 23:46:08.809 Sync[76882:3531763] Buffer scheduled - signaled value: 2
2022-01-09 23:46:08.809 Sync[76882:3531763] Buffer completed - signaled value: 2
```

As you can see `eventListener` logs buffer status as `.commited`.
What’s the matter here? Am I missing something?

System: macOS 12.0.1, Apple M1 Pro, Xcode 13.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine that command buffer is committed. In fact if it wouldn't be committed you'll never get to `notify` block.

GPU and CPU runs in parallel. So when you use `MTLEvent` you don't stop executing CPU code (all the Swift code actually). You just tell GPU in what order to execute GPU code.

So what's happening in your case:

1. All your code runs in a single CPU thread without any interruption.
2. GPU starts executing command buffer commands only when you call `commit()`. Before it GPU actually don't do anything. You just scheduled command to be performed on GPU but don't perform them.
3. When GPU executes commands it checks for your `MTLEvent`. It performs part 1, then encodes value `1` to event, performs notify block, encodes value `2`, performs second GPU block.

But again all the actual GPU work starts only when you call `commit()` on command buffer. That's why buffer is already committed in notify block. Because it is performed after `commit()`.

Comment: I see that. But why isn't it `.scheduled`? From what I understand notification block should be called after GPU performed command encoded before signaling event.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I thought that you asked why buffer is already committed in notify block. I don't know the exact answer why it is not scheduled already in CPU stage but according to `.scheduled` status docs

A command buffer is considered scheduled when any dependencies between work tasks submitted by other command buffers or other APIs in the system are satisfied.

Maybe MTLEvent is that "other API" ))

Comment: Ok, after evaluating the contents of buffer after execution, it indeed seems like the tasks are executed in correct order (value of 22 in range 0…127 inside CPU block, and 23 afterwards). I was totally fooled by command buffer not being `.scheduled` inside CPU block and scheduled/completed handler log order…

Comment: Your assumptions are probably correct, thanks for the help :)